# Block overflowing parent block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm actually learning how to code with bootstrap and something pretty weird is happening to me.
I want to build a basic template with a title row and a middle row.
the middle row has to be grey on the background and white in the center (where the content is).
the middle row has a flex-grow so that the background colors are everywhere, no just depending of the content size.
But when this content is big, it overflows the row, and I can't figure out why.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Potatoe Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file/file.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row titleRow">
            <div class = "col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-6">
                <div id="titleArea">
                    <h1 id="title">Potatoe</h1>
                    <p>blablabla</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row scndRow">
            <div class = "col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-6 middleColumn">
                <div id="testBlock">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-sm-3">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
h1[id=title]
{
    font-size: 200%;    
}

.titleRow
{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.scndRow
{
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}

.middleColumn
{
    background-color: white;
}

#testBlock
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: blue;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[my display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKaC7.jpg)

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give us an example in which case it overflows? So we exactly now what you try to prevent.

Comment: When the testBlock has a too big height to be fully seen in the screen. then i use the scroll bar and we can see the overflow as on my screenshot. Actually it is more obvious with:
.middleColumn
{
 background-color: green;
}
-> http://imgur.com/a5oLMI8
one of the problem is that this overflow happen not on every browser, actually just on chrome for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay problem solved:
I replaced the height: 100% by a min-height: 100% (for html and body)

when i set a height: 100%, chrome consider that i want it to be 100% of the viewport. when my testBlock is bigger, it should make the row bigger and so the body. so the body's height would be bigger than 100%. so it can't, and the testBlock overflow.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the `flex` properties to class `scndRow` ?
and set `height:100%` to element that have to be?

You have to specify it to `scndRow` which is wrapping the two other colunm classes AND to these columns.

```
.scndRow{
  height:100%;
}

.scndRow .col-sm-3
{
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}

.middleColumn
{
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Just for the example, I added a jQuery function to make you see the effect of more content in the `testBlock`.

See it in [updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/2yvL76t5/)

Comment: I specified a height:900px just to simulate a content.
in real i don't have this of course, I just made another code to see more precisely when the overflow occur

Comment: ok.. So what about `max-height:100%;` and `overflow:hidden` ? I guess you dont want the overflow to be hidden... Could you precise your question with a real problem definition ?

Comment: the block #middleColumn contain various stuffs, such as input an so on. When there are too many stuffs inside, it should simply make this block bigger (and so the row), but it doesn't. indeed, i don't want the overflow to be hidden :/

Comment: indeed if i remove the flex properties there is no overflow anymore, but i need it, i want these blocks to grow and fill the remaining space.
if i remove it i have this:
http://imgur.com/a/nY29i
but i want this:
http://imgur.com/a/VcMpO

Comment: (i mean if the content is smaller, and it can be)

Comment: I understand.. I edited again. It should work now. ;)

Comment: i tried it but if i do that, the body will be too big and a scrollbar will appear even if it is not needed. because the content of the body will have a height of: height of the titleRow + 100% of the ... original body size i guess, or screen size.
the problem is more obvious there :
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Bes7weB/2yvL76t5/show/ (the source code is the one that you did)
so i thought about specify a height to titleRow to (for example 20%) and setting the remain to scndRow (80%), but i don't want to specify a height to titleRow, it can cut the display of the text inside :/